# Listview chat appearance not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I m creating a sms app for that I am working with chat list appearance here is my Chatlist adapter class.

chatlistAdapter.java:

```
public class chatList_AdapterClass extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<chatList_row> mArrayList;
ViewHolder mHolder=null;

public chatList_AdapterClass(Context context, ArrayList<chatList_row> arrayList) {
    mContext = context;
    mArrayList = arrayList;
}

public class ViewHolder{

    TextView mReceivedMessage;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams mParams;


    ViewHolder(View v){
        mReceivedMessage=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ChatListMessages);


    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return mArrayList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row=ConvertView;
    if (row == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_list_row,parent,false);


        mHolder=new ViewHolder(row);
        mHolder.mParams=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)mHolder.mReceivedMessage.getLayoutParams();
        row.setTag(mHolder);
    }else {

        mHolder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();

    }

    mHolder.mReceivedMessage.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getMessageContent());

    boolean send=mArrayList.get(position).getTypeofMessage().equals("send");
    setChatRowAppearance(send,mHolder);

    return row;
}

public  void setChatRowAppearance(boolean send,ViewHolder mHolder){


    if (send){
        mHolder.mParams.gravity= Gravity.END;
        mHolder.mReceivedMessage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mHolder.mReceivedMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble2);

    }else {

        mHolder.mParams.gravity= Gravity.START;
        mHolder.mReceivedMessage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mHolder.mReceivedMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble1);


    }

}




}
```

1. when I am sending and receiving SMS I am saving it to a database
2. Retrieving that from database and passing to a arraylist
3. From that arraylist I am creating chat appearance left and right
4. The problem is the after a sms send and receive the new sms should appear  below the previous message but here my new messages are also appears in previous sms like ....

> SEND SMS
>           1
>           3
>     Received sms
>           2
>           4

Comment: pls, format tour code in a right way

Comment: Yes,i did please help me to overcome this issue

Comment: Post screen pls.

Comment: It's not going to fix your problem, but you should look at [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). You are duplicating some it's functionality.